# What is the cost of having a Google Cloud Storage bucket with no data in it?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I was going through https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/storage-classes. It is showing the price of different storage classes in per GB per Month. Does the empty bucket doesn't cost you anything, otherwise what will be the charges?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about service pricing

Comment: Please see pricing page --> https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in the [Cloud Storage pricing](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing) documentation there is a free tier of 5 Gb. So, having an empty bucket will have no fee.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a GCS bucket is a [Class A operation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#operations-pricing), which means you'll be charged up to 5-10 cents for every 10,000 buckets you create. There is not a charge for the buckets existing, and the buckets themselves can also be deleted for free (although their may be a charge for deleting some of the objects inside them, such as very new coldline objects).

Therefore buckets are very, very cheap for any reasonable number of buckets. That said, there are quotas and such around their creation. Creating a massive number of them is usually not the best design.

Answer (score 1):

Read carefully the pricing. 0 Gb doesn't mean free. If you create/delete a lot of empty file for keeping state or something else, your are also charge of Class A operation. Of course, when the file size are not null, these fee are invisible, but if you misuse the service (use it instead a database), you will be charged!

Comment: I am making a service like Wix, where I will store each client's files in a different bucket for management and security reasons, does that mean that creating all websites in the same bucket will have different charges? and how high will these charges be?

Comment: Having 1 bucket per client, or one for all client won't change the charge. I don't know service like wix, but keep in mind that Cloud Storage is not a file system.  High throughput read/write operation are very bad.